# SXA Autosuggestion work after two characters

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1` and `SXA 1.8`, the autosuggest works after entering two characters if I want to change it and make it work like after three characters, Where can I change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in `component-search-box` script, there is hardcoded value `2`:

```
typeahead = this.$el.find(".search-box-input").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 2
}
```

I don't know if there is any easy way to change it via config but worst scenario, you can edit the content of the script and use whatever value you want.

Comment: I made this change since no option to configure.

Comment: @MichaelWest That would be a good improvement. I will note this in our backlog.

Comment: Thanks too much for your effort, this helped me.